# how to check @Before is working in play framework

Tags: annotations, playframework

I'm running play application.

I have

```
import org.junit.Before;
public class Frontpage extends Controller {
    @Before
    private static void commonData() {
            Map cacheMap = Cache.get("login_det",Map.class);
            System.out.println("commonData");
            if(cacheMap!=null)
            {
             renderArgs.put("login_det", cacheMap);
             System.out.println("renderArgs"+renderArgs.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But commonData is never printed in my console. How can i check @Before is working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `org.junit.Before` annotation, which is used by JUnit to run a method before a unit test execution.

In your case, you should use the [`play.mvc.Before`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.2/play/mvc/Before.html) annotation instead.

Comment: Good spot!  I've totally done that before.  Eclipse's utility to easily add import statements doesn't help either, because I just click one rather than thinking about what I actually need.

Answer (score 2):

And instead of using `System.out.println`, try using `Logger.info/debug/error/trace`. 
They are the standard output for Play applications.